# How to pass the time to the DateTimeField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

In my models.py I have a GTTime model:

```
class GTTime(models.Model):
    gt_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And in my views.py, how to add the time to in the gt_time?

I tried use the `time.time()` to pass the timestamp, but there will report error:

```
gt = models.GTTime(gt_time=time.time())
gt.save()
```

Error: `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Answer (score 3):

From the [django datetime doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)

> A date and time, represented in Python by a datetime.datetime instance. Takes the same extra arguments as DateField.

but you you gives a time instance, take the bellow code:

```
gt = models.GTTime(testTime=datetime.now())

gt.save()
```